# Why can't I multiply size by integer in calc?

Tags: lengths, calc

This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\foo}
\newcommand{\zzz}{5}
\setlength{\foo}{\zzz * 2in}
\usepackage[paperwidth=\foo,paperheight=\foo]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   *
l.5 \setlength{\foo}{\zzz * 2in}
```

How to do it right?

Comment: you can also use `\setlength{\foo}{2in}` `\setlength{foo}{\zzz\foo}` (no calc needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordering of the arguments of the `\setlength` instruction matters. Your code has

```
\newlength{\foo}
\newcommand{\zzz}{5}
\setlength{\foo}{\zzz * 2in}
```

TeX starts with a scalar number (5) and is told to multiply it by a length (2in). Such on-the-fly type changes -- here: from scalar to length variable -- aren't allowed.

In contrast, the syntax of the expression

```
\setlength{\foo}{2in * \zzz}
```

is perfectly acceptable, as TeX starts with a length (2in) and multiplies it by a scalar (5), resulting in another length (10in).

Comment: Interestingly, if we have `\newcommand{\zzz}{5}`, then `\setlength{\foo}{\zzz in * 2}` is also valid, syntactically speaking. In my view, though, this alternative takes a bit more time to parse -- from a human perspective at least.

Comment: Another disadvantage of that order would of course be that it doesn't generalises to the situation where the base length doesn't happen to be an integer multiple of an inch (or whatever your unit of choice is) :).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\foo}
\newcommand{\zzz}{5}
\setlength{\foo}{ 2in * \zzz }
\usepackage[paperwidth=\foo,paperheight=\foo]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```